# How to make a button pointing towards right or left?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-button, rounded-corners

I wish to use a button of this shape,pointing to right or left in my app.

Two corners of the button are rounded, and the other side is triangular.

I was able to accomplish this somewhat using a png image as background, but I would prefer to know how to do it in xml.

[image]

Comment: you can create a drawable shape and use it as background. or just look for a library on GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the exact way to do that, but you could always increase the `radius` of the `topLeft` and `bottomLeft` or Right to maximum, to get a semicircular pointing end. 
This is how I tried to do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
android:topRightRadius="31dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="31dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#7995A8"
android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="linear"
/>
<size
android:width="172dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

[This is how it looks..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFXkJ.png)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. But, could work with it for now.

Comment: why you used padding ??

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice is to use images for complex shapes. In case you a trying to control the app size, you could use one image that points in one direction and rotate it in drawable xml to point the other way.

However, if you really want implement this in xml, I have got a triangle pointing left/ right below. You can try improving on this to suit your requirement.

Right Pointing,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Right pointing sample image]

Left Pointing,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Left point sample image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shape like that using layer list, read more about layer list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList). This should give you the desired output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#5e88b8" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="-40dp"
        android:bottom="65dp"
        android:left="-30dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="65dp"
        android:bottom="-40dp"
        android:left="-30dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and then set it as the button background :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="button" />
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image: Check here]

**UPDATE**

Change the corner radius to get the desired corner look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MaterialButton` with the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute:

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CutAndRound"
            />
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CutAndRound" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]